# Parsing "HH:mm:ss" and "H:m:s" times using DateTime.ParseExact()

Tags: c#

I want to be able to parse the following times using ParseExact() function:

```
01:02:03
1:02:03
1:2:03
1:02:3
01:2:3
1:2:3
```

Is it possible, or do I need to do my own conversions so it work?

So far I can parse only all with leading 0 or all without leading zero.
I can do it with 6 format strings but i think this is pretty stupid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `ParseExact` with the "H:m:s" custom format string works perfectly for all the examples given in your question.

```
string[] test = { "01:02:03", "1:02:03", "1:2:03", "1:02:3", "01:2:3", "1:2:3" };

foreach (string s in test)
{
    DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "H:m:s", null);
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?  All strings parse without a problem in this sample code:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string[] dates = new string[] { "01:02:03", "1:02:03", "1:2:03", "1:02:3", "01:2:3", "1:2:3" };
        foreach (string date in dates) {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "H:m:s", null);
            Console.WriteLine(dt);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
11/9/2009 1:02:03 AM
11/9/2009 1:02:03 AM
11/9/2009 1:02:03 AM
11/9/2009 1:02:03 AM
11/9/2009 1:02:03 AM
11/9/2009 1:02:03 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the purpose of `ParseExact()` requires an exact match of the format string.  Is there a reason not to simply use the `Parse()` method instead?

Comment: because Parse() can accept some input that is not valid and i cant do anything to valide that

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `Parse`? As its name implies, `ParseExact` is used when you have exactly one input format and all others must be rejected.